# how to extract fields data from filtered object django

Tags: django, django-models

By below line m getting

```
members = Member.objects.filter(profile=profiles)
```

i want to pass memeber with field name in this line same as here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

```
member_formset = MemberFormSet(initial=members)
```

gives me an error

```
'Member' object is not iterable
```

please suggest best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass only one object to initial, e.g. members[0]. Filter returns list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass objects as `initial` to a formset (it's for a dictionary of values). Use `queryset=members` instead.

Comment: geting this error if i pass queryset `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'`

Comment: That means you're not using a [modelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), which you should be.